# Django DRF serializer - inserting data containing foreign key relationships

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'contact'

class ContactPhone(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    number = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'contact_phone'
```

Also, I have the following serializers:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    server_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'

class ContactPhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ContactPhone
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, I have a view that insert phone numbers for an existing contact.
The input is a json that looks like this:

```
data = {'contact_id': 12322,
        'phones':[{'number': '89120000001'}]}
```

The view:

```
def insert_contact_phone(request):
    for record in request.data['phones']:
        data['contact_id'] = request.data['contact_id']
        serializer = ContactPhoneSerializer(data = data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
```

I end up with the following error:

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /contacts/edit ContactPhone has no
>   contact.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `__all__` for the fields in your ContactPhoneSerializer, it does not include contact_id.

So the contact_id taken from the json input is not serialized. It is basically ignored and when you try to save and create new ContactPhone - it fails, because it does not have contact's foreign key correctly set.

But simply adding contact_id to the serializer's fields won't solve your problem.

In your view, i recommend you to set the contact instead:

```
data['contact'] = request.data['contact_id']
```

and pass this to the ContactPhoneSerializer.